# Don't hide selectfield picker after click on mask [Modern 6.6]

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-modern

As you can see in the fiddle below, I have a **selectfield** with an **edgepicker** and I wish they could **not be closed other than with its own button.**

But it closes when you click outside yourself, on the background mask for example.

I tried the property `hideOnMaskTap: false` but **without** success and after spending several hours searching in the doc and in the source code of Extjs I found nothing...

**Have you ever faced this problem?**

Thank you for your help.

### Fiddle : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2rbo

Answer (score 0):

Came to the conclusion that you can achieve the desired behavior by overriding the methods `onFocusLeave and`collapseIf`. Picker collapse when tap on mask happens in them

```
Ext.define('Ext.field.PickerOverride', {
  override: 'Ext.field.Picker',
  collapseIf:  Ext.emptyFn,
  onFocusLeave: Ext.emptyFn
});
```

or change the behavior of these methods as you need.